# The controller request returns a status code of 401, I don't understand why, though I wrote down everything I needed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing a web ap project, using Asp.net cor 3.1, I described the return of the token generation when when sending a request to the controller with the attribute  [Authorize] I return the status code 401, and I do not understand why, a lot of information I read, nothing helped.
my controller

```
[Authorize]
    public class SchoolRequestController : BaseController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(201)]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<long>> Create([FromBody] RegisterSchoolCommand command)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            try
            {
                var account = await Mediator.Send(command).ConfigureAwait(false);
                return Ok(command);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

my ConfigureServices

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //add AutoMapper
            services.AddAutoMapper(new Assembly[] { typeof(AutoMapperProfile).GetTypeInfo().Assembly });
            services.AddFluentValidation(new[] { typeof(AutoMapperProfile).GetTypeInfo().Assembly });
            // add mediatr
            services.AddMediatR(typeof(LoginCommandHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPerformanceBehaviour<,>));

            services.AddControllers();
            var connectionStringName = "YPSDataBase";
            // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "My API",
                    Version = "v1"
                });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "Please insert JWT with Bearer into field",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                });
                var security = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    {"Bearer", new string[] { }},
                };
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                        {

                        }, new string[] { }

                    }
                });
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                if (File.Exists(xmlPath))
                {
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
                }
            });
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["ApiKey"]);
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    };
                });
            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
            });
            services.AddDbContext<IYPSDbContext, YPSDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName),
                    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("YPS.Persistence")
                ));
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .Build());
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

and my class Configure

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            if (env.IsDevelopment())    
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pay attention to [Middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) , you should place `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.UseAuthorization();` . Modify your Configure class to :

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```